# Java Maze Game Player Movement Not Working

Tags: java, swing, jframe, maze

For my coding project, I have to code a maze game. However, I currently have a maze displayed in a JFrame, with the player being represented by a red square, the end marker is a blue square and the walls are black squares. But no matter what I try and do I can't seem to get the player to move around the maze.

```
package practiceMazeGame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MazeBoard extends JFrame{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// Creates the maze board using a 2D array.
public static int[][] maze =
    {{3,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1},
    {1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1},
    {1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},
    {0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1},
    {0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1},
    {0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1},
    {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0},
    {0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0},
    {0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0},
    {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0},
    {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,2},
    };

//Sets the output screen information
public MazeBoard() {
    // Displays 'Maze Game' in the title bar of the window.
    setTitle("Maze Game");
    // Sets the size of the output screen.
    setSize(640, 640);
    // Sets the location of where the window will appear.
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    // Stops the program when the window is closed.
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    PlayerMovement mySquare = new PlayerMovement(640, 640);   
    add(mySquare);

}

// The function in charge of the graphics of the maze.
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.translate(50, 50);

    // They go through every section of the 2D array to make sure all the blocks are covered.
    for (int row =0; row <maze.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < maze[0].length; col++) {
            Color color;
            switch(maze[row][col]){
                // Sets the colour of the blocks of the array with a one to be black.
                case 1 : color = Color.black; break;
                // Sets the colour villain to be red.
                case 2 : color = Color.red; break;
                // Sets the colour of the player to be blue.
                case 3 : color = Color.blue; break;
                // Sets the colour of the rest of the maze to be white.
                default : color = Color.white; break;
            }

            // Sets the screen the for behind the maze.
            g.setColor(color);
            // Fills the rectangle needed for the maze with the colours previously decided.
            g.fillRect(30 * col, 30 * row, 30, 30);
            // Sets the colour of the gird lines for the maze.
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            // Draws the rectangle needed for the maze.
            g.drawRect(30 * col, 30 * row, 30, 30);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Outputs the maze.
            MazeBoard view = new MazeBoard();
            view.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

I would really appreciate some help, thank you.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Instead of posting all the code of your maze, it would be much better if you posted the snippet of code you have used as an attempt to allow player movement.

Comment: Is the PlayerMovement class a custom one you created?

Comment: Where is the code that you are using to try to move the player?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for you:

- Storing the player's position in your array (as a 3 value) is poor design: you should use that just for maze design and store the player's position in separate variables
- Your colouring switch statement could first check if the position being drawn matches the player's position to determine where the blue square should be. Or alternatively you could draw that square after you've drawn the maze
- Moving should then be pretty trivial: just change the player's position variables after checking there is no wall in the new position